# (C++) How to use Payload Object to imiplement thread pool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I saw this very well implemented thread pool: https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool. I am wondering whether I can use a payload object instead. The idea is that instead of using a function pointer, use an object to describe the payload, which always contains a run function and a promise. The main thread then wait on the future of the promise.

Here is what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class GenericPayload {
protected:
  std::promise <int> m_returnCode;
public:
  virtual void run() = 0;
  std::future <int> getFuture() {
    return m_returnCode.get_future();
  }
};

class MyPayload:public GenericPayload {
private:
  int m_input1;
  int m_input2;
  int m_result;
public:
  MyPayload(int input1, int input2):m_input1(input1), m_input2(input2) {}

  void run() {
    m_result = m_input1 * m_input2;
    m_returnCode.set_value(0);
  }

  int getResult() {
    return m_result;
  }
};

class ThreadPool {
private:
  std::queue <GenericPayload *> payloads;
  std::mutex queue_mutex;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::vector< std::thread > workers;
  bool stop;
public:
  ThreadPool(size_t threads)
    :   stop(false)
  {
    for(size_t i = 0;i<threads;++i)
      workers.emplace_back(
               [this]
               {
                 for(;;)
                   {
                 GenericPayload *payload;

                 {
                   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
                   this->cv.wait(lock,
                         [this]{ return this->stop || !this->payloads.empty(); });
                   if(this->stop)
                     return;
                   payload = this->payloads.front();
                   this->payloads.pop();
                 }

                 payload->run();
                   }
               }
               );
  }

  void addPayLoad (GenericPayload *payload) {
    payloads.push(payload);
  }

  ~ThreadPool()
  {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
      stop = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
    for(std::thread &worker: workers)
      worker.join();
  }

    
};

int main() {
  MyPayload myPayload(3, 5);
  ThreadPool threadPool(2);
  std::future <int> returnCode = myPayload.getFuture();
  threadPool.addPayLoad(&myPayload);
  returnCode.get();
  std::cout << myPayload.getResult() << std::endl;
}
```

Is this the right way to do it though? I had to pass a pointer to the payload because 1. I want GenericPayload to be abstract and 2. std::promise is not copyable. Thx for any feedback.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)

Comment: My understanding (which can very well be wrong) is that packaged_task has no state info other than the promise (i.e. it is a wrapper around a function). Yes, I can pass an object reference as a parameter, but having the entire thing as an object feels more nature to me. MyPayload can be super complex with multiple level of inheritance.

Comment: `packaged_task` accepts any callable object in its constructor. That object may very well carry state. E.g. it could be a lambda with captures.

Comment: Good point. How can I modify my code to use packaged_task, but still pass either a reference or a pointer of an object into the addPayload function (Just realized I forgot to take the mutex, please ignore that)? I tried `auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<int ()>>([payload] () {return payload->run();}); `, but compiler complains `error: passing const MyPayload’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]` Thx.

Comment: `[myObj] () mutable {return myObj.run();}` Though `run()` returns `void`, so it's unclear how you expect the task to produce an `int`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the run function to return a int (which is the reasonCode). 
```
class MyPayload {
private:
  int m_input1;
  int m_input2;
  int m_result;
public:
  MyPayload(int input1, int input2):m_input1(input1), m_input2(input2), m_result(-2) {}

  int run() {
    m_result = m_input1 * m_input2;
    return 0;
  }

  int getResult() {
    return m_result;
  }
};```

Comment: Many Thanks. That worked great (had to capture by reference).